# What does "cold war" between couples mean

Tags: phrases

When a couple stops communicating, is that called cold war? Or is that part of cold war? In English, is cold war not limited to giving each other a silent treatment?

Comment: 'The Cold War' is an expression coined to describe the period of tension between the USSR and the 'West' following World War 2. A use of the term to describe personal relationships is metaphorical and can't be precisely defined.

Comment: Re the title - a cold war 'between couples' would be a war between one or more separate couples. I think this topic is a cold war between members of a couple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Cold War" implies a sustained conflict that's waged almost entirely indirectly or passively, without obvious aggression.

So if a couple gets in a fight at a party but has to drive home together and won't talk the entire drive, "cold war" is probably too excessive of a descriptor for what's currently happening.

Think about the opposite of a cold war. If a couple was in a war, what would that be like? Not a single fight. But a series of conflicts that involve direct attacks (not necessarily physical) at the other person.

Now if they were in a cold war, not talking could be part of that. But it wouldn't be the only part. They'd still have to be in some kind of indirect conflict. For example, they're not communicating, but she goes and buys a new car and posts about it, saying how much happier she is. Then he goes and busy a new truck and posts about it, saying how much happier he is.

When Russia and the U.S. were in the Cold War, they'd do things like both trying to go to space first. Or seeing who could win more gold medals at the Olympics. Or if the US were supporting one country in the Middle East, Russia might support the opposition to that country.

That can apply to people as well. If they break up and work together, they might both try and be the highest earners in the company without directly acknowledging they are competing. Or maybe they have a mutual friend and the girl starts dating the mutual friend while the guy then pursues one of the girl's friends.

So, to be "war", there usually has to be some kind of larger, longer campaign where the two entities compete in some capacity. Not communicating can be part of that but not all of it.